# jQuery addClass not working?

Tags: jquery, addclass

I'm trying to build a website but I keep getting the same problem.

Once the page loads, I want to add a class to the menu item (active) so it looks selected. This is the code I use (it's located just before the closing body tag).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#navList li a#navHome').addClass('active');
});
```

The HTML is like this:

```
<ul id="navList">
    <li><a href="index.php" title="Home" id="navHome">home</a></li>
</ul>
```

However, when I inspect the element, no class gets added. I really can't find out what I'm doing wrong?

The jQuery file is linked correctly because other jQuery code works.

Comment: did you try to appaned a string or somesing instand of addclass()? becuse it might be the selector

Comment: What do you mean by string instead of addClass?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sp88X/ - example. What happen in console ?

Comment: instead of this u could just add the `active` class to ur HTMLm :) (just saying) - `<a href="index.php" title="Home" class="active" id="navHome">`

Comment: Since IDs are unique you can just use this selector `$('#navHome').addClass('active')`. As for why it's not working: are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Seems working to me... http://jsfiddle.net/3Pzpr/ Also, **ID** are supposed to be unique in DOM, so this also works http://jsfiddle.net/3Pzpr/1/

Comment: Nope, nothing in the console. The navigation (so the HTML) is included with an include_once though, does that matter maybe?

Comment: Problem solved... I put the jQuery on top my other codes (just after first body tag) and removed the other jQuery codes... weird. But it's fixed now!

Comment: That doesn't matter as the whole document will be in one piece when the client side JS will be executed. Are you loading jQuery correctly?

Comment: @Bogdan most likely the code showed in the question was put before loading of jQuery and the error was that $ is not defined :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try these:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#navList li a').addClass('active');
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/82s6F/)

Comment: it doesn't address the core of the question, which is how to correctly target that particular <a>. what if there were several of those with different id's?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#navHome').addClass('active');
});
```